# How to create nested JSON response

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot to handle exceptions and return timestamp, message and details.

My exception class is as follows:

[image]

My JSON response is:

[image]

My question is, how do I return:

```
Exception: {
    "timestamp": "2018-10-02T17:07:31.095+0000",
    "message": "id: 45267",
    "details": "uri=/v1/users/45267"
}
```

Comment: Your desired return is not a valid JSON response. Did you mean `{ "Exception": {
    "timestamp": "2018-10-02T17:07:31.095+0000",
    "message": "id: 45267",
    "details": "uri=/v1/users/45267"
}}` ?

Comment: Please add the code an not an image of the code.

Comment: BTW, you  need to provide the code where you create this response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON format is directly mapped with corresponding Java Class design.
In your case following declaration would do -

```
class ExceptionResponse {
    private CustomException exception;
}
class CustomException {
    private Date timestamp;
    private Message message; //can even split message further.
    private String details;
}

class Message {
    private int id;
    private String category;
    private String comment;
}
```

Output JSON of ExceptionResponse would be :

```
exception: {
    "timestamp":"...",
    "message": {
          "id":"...",
          "category":"...",
          "comment":"..."
    },
    "details":"..."
}
```